# Adding markers or lines to colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have the following lines of code to generate a heatmap (`pcolormesh`).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

vals = np.linspace(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2, 101)
x, y = np.meshgrid(vals, vals)

z = np.abs(np.sinc(x) * np.sinc(y))

xDeg = np.rad2deg(x)
yDeg = np.rad2deg(y)

plt.pcolormesh(xDeg, yDeg, z, cmap='jet', vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar()

plt.axis([-90, 90, -90, 90])
ticks = np.linspace(-90, 90, 13)
plt.xticks(ticks)
plt.yticks(ticks)

print(np.mean(z))                # 0.186225110029
print(np.sqrt(np.mean(z**2)))    # 0.295710882276
plt.show()
```

It produces this image:
[image: pcolormesh result]

I'd like to place:

1. A marker on the colorbar at the mean (0.186).
2. A horizontal line on the colorbar at the RMS value (0.295).

Any input?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That was easier than expected. I didn't realize colorbar has a plottable axis in `plt.colorbar().ax`

```py
    cb = plt.colorbar()
    cb.ax.plot(0.5, mean, 'w.')
    cb.ax.plot([0, 1], [rms]*2, 'w')
```

OR, as @OrOrg pointed out,

```py
    cb = plt.colorbar()
    cb.ax.plot(0.5, mean, 'w.')
    cb.ax.axhline(rms, c='w')
```

<strike>Looks like the x-axis is (0, 1) and y-axis <strike>(dataMin, dataMax)</strike> (0, 1).</strike>

Per @S.A. comment, x/y-axis are between `(min(data), max(data))`. However, this example is showing the x-axis is `(0, 1)` where x-axis data is `(-pi/2, pi/2)`. Y-axis is confirmed to be `(min(data), max(data))`.

[image: pcolormesh with markers on colorbar.]

Comment: The x-axis and y-axis of the colorbar axes object are both in terms of the data. Only in your example this is by chance `(0, 1)`. In all cases the x-axis and y-axis will both have the limits `(min(data), max(data))`

Comment: It might be clearer/more robust to use `cb.ax.axhline(rms, c='w')` for the horizontal line.

Comment: @OrOrg - great point.