# How to add a line on the colorbar of an imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

Basically, I found [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446066/adding-markers-or-lines-to-colorbar-in-matplotlib) instructions on how to add a custom line or point on a colorbar, but nothing happens with my code.

I tried changing the zorder, or switching to the pyplot style, but still couldn't get it to work.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='rainbow')

cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im)
cbar.outline.set_visible(False)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel("α", rotation=0, va="bottom")
# None of them does anything
cbar.ax.plot(0.5, 0.5, 'k.', label="Ref")
cbar.ax.plot(0.5, 3, 'k.', label="Ref")
cbar.ax.plot([0, 1], [3, 3], 'k', label="Ref")
```

The figure so far looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSmIz.png)

I am using matplotlib 3.1.1

Comment: A y-value of 0.5 is not in the range (limits) of your color bar. You would need something between about 1.8 and 7.2.

Comment: I thought x,y was in percentage of axis range, but even if I use something like y=3, I get nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib will set the x and y limits of the colorbar to the same values. So if the y limits of your color bar are 1.8 and 7.2, the x limits are as well. You will need to plot within these limits to see your markers.

Using `axhline` might be an easier option instead of plotting a line with `plot`. To label this marked value, you can add it to the colorbar ticks and ticklabels.

```
# clim = cbar.ax.get_ylim()          # find axis limits
# cbar.ax.plot(mean(clim), 3, 'k.')  # point at 3 in the middle of x axis
cbar.ax.axhline(y=3, c='w')          # line at 3

# Set label
original_ticks = list(cbar.get_ticks())
cbar.set_ticks(original_ticks + [3])
cbar.set_ticklabels(original_ticks + ['Ref'])
```

[image]

Comment: This seems so strange to me, is there a reason I am missing to give the x-axis these values?

Comment: Thanks, this works, but the label is still not visible.

Comment: Ok, got a label using text() for now, but something else is happening. When drawing a line, it doesn't cover the whole width of the bar, either when using axhline() or plot([np.min(data), np.max(data)], [3, 3], 'k').

Comment: I'm not sure why that wouldn't work for you. It works fine for me using `text`. Can you provide the code you tried? Regardless, I edited my answer with perhaps a cleaner way to label your marked point on the colorbar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will use that. text() was working as well, it was the label in axhline() that wasn't showing. But the line still doesn't cover a few pixels on both sides of the colorbar.

Comment: Are you still unable to have the line cover the entire x range of the colorbar? I can't replicate that issue as you see in the pic I attached. You could update your post with the code you are using and a picture showing this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) instead of `plot` in this case.  The label you specified in `plot` call won't show up until a `legend()` call, and even in that case the legend will not show up where you want them to be.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(np.random.normal(size=100).reshape(10, 10), cmap='rainbow')

cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im)
cbar.outline.set_visible(False)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel("α", rotation=0, va="bottom")
cbar.ax.annotate('Ref', (0, 0))
```

[image]