# How can I draw a line at a specific value on a colorbar while using Xarray?

Tags: python, plot, python-xarray, colorbar

I am using xarray to plot 2D maps but I want to specify values on the colorbar with lines or markers.
[Adding markers or lines to colorbar in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446066/adding-markers-or-lines-to-colorbar-in-matplotlib) shows how to add lines to a colorbar that is added to a plot. But with the built in colorbar in xarray, it seems the only way to alter the colorbar is with cmap_kwargs. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: xarray returns a matplotlib axis object, so you can always find the colorbar object within the axis object's collections. alternatively, you can not use the built in colorbar and then create the colorbar manually. ultimately, this will have to be done using matplotlib, as there's no built in xarray method for adding a line on top of the default colorbar.